# Pandas query not working in some versions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['john','david','anna'],
    'country':['USA','UK',np.nan]
})

df.query('country.isnull()')
```

This runs for me in pandas, it doesn't run for some of my teammates (whose installation process I don't control), but we have the same pandas version (1.3.4).

They get:

```py
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Can anybody help me understand why this code works differently on different computers?

Apparently, some people have this issue as well: [blog](https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-query-examples-sql-like-syntax-queries-in-dataframes#typeerror-unhashable-type-series).

Comment: Did you try adding the `engine="python"` parameter as suggested in the link you pasted?

Comment: yeah, but even without the engine python it works for me, my question is, why does it work in some computers and not in others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the reason is having numexpr installed or not:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/34251#issuecomment-732769686